# Matches gives me error when searched string is not found

Tags: javascript

I need to check for the existance of `tr.workingRow` inside of `event.composedPath()`

I tried `event.composedPath().some(x => x.matches('tr.workingRow'))` and it returns **true** if found. That's perfect for me. Unfortunately, it does not returns **false** otherwise and I got an error at runtime.

[image]

As you can see below when searching for something that does not exists, I get an error: x.matches is not a function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add a condition to check for the type of 'x' to be of string type, and then call the matches function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

last two Elements returned by [composedPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) (`#document` and `window`) are not a type of [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) that implement [.mathes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) so calling `.matches()` on them will cause a type error as we can see. hence the selector you are looking for if it reaches the last two element is not found; and the `typeError` can be fixed with a `truthy` check like this;

```js
e.composedPath().some(cpe => cpe.matches ? cpe.matches("tr"): false)
```

```js
document.querySelector("#root").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let result = e.composedPath().some(cpe => cpe.matches ? cpe.matches("tr"): false)
  console.log(result)
});
```

```html
<div id="root">
  div
  <p>
    p
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is finally what I found on my side.